# Postgresql Use a specified value instead of first_value

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to replace first_value and use a specified value to use in an equation because of alpha sort I'm having an issue. I want to use a value in a row called 'control' which is in the segment column and direct_mail_test table. So I need to find a way to call just that value ('control') to then use in the equation. New to PostgreSQL, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my current code

```
select segment,
    count(*) as total,
    count(b.c_guid) as bookings,
    100.0 * count(b.c_guid)/count(*) as percent,
    100.0 * count(b.c_guid) / first_value(count(b.c_guid)) over ( order by segment asc ) as comp
from mailing_tests
    left join (
        select distinct g.contact_guid as c_guid
        from guest g 
            inner join booking
                on booking.guid = g.booking_guid
        where booking.book_date >= {{date_start}}
            [[and booking.book_date < {{date_end}}]]
            and booking.status in ('Booked')
        ) b
        on mailing_tests.guid = b.c_guid
where {{project}}
group by segment
order by segment asc 

Here is my output:

    segment
                  total bookings percent comp
catalog           4,091    30     0.73    100
control          30,611   359     1.17  1,196.67
direct_mail      30,611   393     1.28  1,310
online_ads       30,611   371     1.21  1,236.67
'''
As of now its taking in the 'catalog' as the
 measurable and I need it to take the 'control' as the 
measurable.

Just to put some more context on the code, I am using 
metabase. So the {{date_start}}
      [[and peak15_booking.book_date < {{date_end}}]]
{{project}}
are all variable functions used in metabase.

I tried to use the nth_value, fetch function, and 
many others, but I'm not sure if I am even using 
those properly. I have been unsuccessful in finding 
any answer to this.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make this work, but not sure if it's the cleanest way to do this or if I will run into future issues. I still haven't figured out how to replace first_value, but I did add (order by segment='control' desc) twice. once in the SELECT statement and the other in WHERE clause. Again, not sure if this is the correct way to do this, but thought I would show that I did end up figuring it out. Not sure if I should of answered my own question or deleted it, but thought that this might help someone else.

'

```
    select segment,
    count(*) as total,
    count(b.c_guid) as bookings,
    100.0 * count(b.c_guid) / count(*) as percent,
    100.0 * count(b.c_guid) / first_value(count(b.c_guid)) over ( order by segment='control' desc, segment asc ) as comp
from mailing_tests
    left join (
        select distinct g.contact_guid as c_guid
        from guest g 
            inner join booking
                on booking.guid = g.booking_guid
        where booking.book_date >= {{date_start}}
            [[and booking.book_date < {{date_end}}]]
            and booking.status in ('Booked')
        ) b
        on mailing_tests.guid = b.c_guid
where {{project}}
group by segment
order by segment='control' desc, segment asc
```

'

Comment: Hi AZ_C3NTUR1ON,  it's fine to answer your own question. Can you post a sample of your data so I can try out some SQL that will do what you want?